# GIF does not animate when content of QLabel is updated from another thread

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt5

I created a simple app which uses PyQt5 to display an image inside a QLabel. The image can be static (ex: png, jpeg, bmp) or it can a gif.

The description of the example code below is as follows:

- Class *ImageDisplayer()* is responsible for creating a QLabel which contains the desired image to be displayed. The *update_image()* method allows the shown image inside the QLabel to be updated to the desired new image. The QLabel window is shown on the desired screen (when using multiple monitors).
- The *main()* method is an simple demo of a PyQt5 app that uses the *ImageDisplayer* class to display a desired image on the QLabel. In the real world end use case, this main Qt app would have other complex widgets/logic for interaction with the user (ex: asking user which image to display) and the QLabel displayed from the ImageDisplayer will always show the desired image in full screen on a secondary monitor. However, for simplicity I have not shown this in the example code below.
- The *test_image_sequence()* method is a simple function which loops through various test images to debug/troubleshoot the development of the *ImageDisplayer()* class.

**Problem:** The ImageDisplayer class works as expected, however, gif images are not animating when I try to call the *update_image()* method from a separate thread. For example, when I run the *test_image_sequence()* method in a separate thread using QThreadPool, the static images are displayed as expected, but gif are not animated.

```py
import os, sys, time, pathlib
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRunnable, QThreadPool
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QPixmap, QMovie
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QWidget

CURRENT_PATH = str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute())

def main():

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv) 

    my_image_window = ImageDisplayer(monitor_num=0,)

    # Method 1: When not using threads, the gif animates as expected 
    # my_image_window.update_image(CURRENT_PATH + r'\test_images\gif_image_2.gif')

    # Method 2: When using threads, gif does NOT animate 
    thread = QThreadPool.globalInstance()
    worker = Worker(test_image_sequence, my_image_window)
    thread.start(worker)

    app.exec_()


def test_image_sequence(widget):
    print('Will start testing seq. of images')
    time.sleep(1)

    images = []
    images.append(CURRENT_PATH + r'\test_images\static_image_1.png')
    images.append(CURRENT_PATH + r'\test_images\static_image_2.png')
    images.append(CURRENT_PATH + r'\test_images\gif_image_1.gif')
    images.append(CURRENT_PATH + r'\test_images\gif_image_2.gif')

    for i in images:
        print('Updating image to:', i)
        widget.update_image(pattern_file=i)
        time.sleep(3)

class ImageDisplayer():
    
    def __init__(self, monitor_num=0,):

        # Get instance of the current QApplication 
        self.app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance() #https://stackoverflow.com/a/53387775/4988010 

        # Gather info on avaliable monitor and select the desired one 
        self.screen = self.app.screens()[monitor_num]
        self.screen_width = self.screen.size().width()
        self.screen_height = self.screen.size().height()

        # Init class attributes
        self.pattern_file = None                        # Set a default pattern if given during init 
        self.pixmap = None                              # Static image content
        self.pixmap_mv = None                           # Movie content

        self.scale_window = 2                           # For debugging: If not full screen the window will be scaled by half of screen size 

        # Define a constant color images when no image displayed 
        self.pixmap_blank = QPixmap(self.screen_width, self.screen_height)
        self.pixmap_blank.fill(QColor('green'))
        self.pixmap = self.pixmap_blank                                     # Default during init

        self.app_widget = None          # QLabel widget object
        self.setupGUI()                 # Setup and show the widget 

    def setupGUI(self):

        print('Setting up the QLabel')

        # Create QLabel object
        self.app_widget = QLabel()
        self.app_widget.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.app_widget.setStyleSheet('QLabel { background-color: green;}')
        self.app_widget.setCursor(Qt.BlankCursor)                       # A blank/invisible cursor, typically used when the cursor shape needs to be hidden.

        # Scale the widget to the size of the screen
        self.app_widget.setGeometry(0, 0, self.screen_width/self.scale_window , self.screen_height/self.scale_window)           # Set the size of Qlabel to size of the screen

        # Set a default pattern during init
        self.app_widget.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        self.app_widget.show()

        # Move window to topleft corner of the selected screen 
        self.app_widget.windowHandle().setScreen(self.screen)
        self.app_widget.move(self.screen.geometry().topLeft())

    def update_image(self, pattern_file):
        self.pattern_file = pattern_file

        print('Pattern file: ', pattern_file)
        filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(pattern_file)       # Get filename and extension https://stackoverflow.com/a/541394/4988010
        
        self.app_widget.clear()                     # Clear all existing content of the QLabel
        self.pixmap = QPixmap(self.pattern_file)

        if (file_extension == '.png') or (file_extension == '.jpg') or (file_extension == '.jpeg') or (file_extension == '.bmp'):
            # File is a static image
            # https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html
            print('Image is a static')
            self.app_widget.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        elif (file_extension == '.gif'):
            # File is a movie
            print('Image is movie')
            self.pixmap_mv = QMovie(self.pattern_file)

            # Connect the "finished() signal to movie_finished() slot"
            self.pixmap_mv.finished.connect(self.movie_finished)

            # Debugging text
            print('Movie is valid: ', self.pixmap_mv.isValid())
            print('loopCount: ', self.pixmap_mv.loopCount())
            print('frameCount: ', self.pixmap_mv.frameCount())
            print('Default speed: ', self.pixmap_mv.speed())

            self.app_widget.setMovie(self.pixmap_mv)
            self.pixmap_mv.start()
            
    def movie_finished(self):

        print('Movie finished')
        # After movie is finished, show blank screen            
        self.app_widget.setPixmap(self.pixmap_blank)

class Worker(QRunnable):

    def __init__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        # Store constructor arguments (re-used for processing)
        self.fn = fn
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def run(self):
        self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic Qt rule: You should not modify the GUI directly from another thread since it is not thread-safe, instead you use the signals. For example in this case you can create a class that is the broker:

```
# ...
class Signaller(QObject):
    imageChanged = pyqtSignal(str)

    def update_image(self, pattern_file):
        self.imageChanged.emit(pattern_file)


def main():

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    my_image_window = ImageDisplayer(monitor_num=0,)

    signaller = Signaller()
    signaller.imageChanged.connect(my_image_window.update_image)

    thread = QThreadPool.globalInstance()
    worker = Worker(test_image_sequence, signaller)
    thread.start(worker)

    app.exec_()
# ...
```